# Color overlay on hover: jquery mosaic plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do you apply a cover overlay on hover to the mosaic elements here: http://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/index.html

The effect I am trying to achieve can be seen here: http://ultravisualtheme.tumblr.com/

I would just copy the second link, but I can't make sense of the code. The reason I ask about doing to the first link is because I can actually understand whats going on there, and could code a site in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to create overlay on top of that div which contains the image. Make it children of that div and use this css:

```
#image:hover > .overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    border-radius:30px;
}
```

You do not actually need any jquery here.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6bjTQ/

But if you want to use jquery anyway, use:

```
$("#image").hover(function() {
    $(".overlay").css({//here goes the same css definition});
}, function() {
    $(".overlay").css({//reset css to default values after you hover out});
});
```

Comment: Aha! That worked, but im having trouble getting text to pop in with the overlay. I can get the text to show up by writing it in the overlay div, setting the opacity to 0, then having in change to 1 on hover, BUT!

Comment: then the text is either dimmed to the opacity of the overlay, or its underneath the overlay, which makes it look dimmed. How can i have the text appear on top of the overlay, on hover? Thanks again!

Comment: Simply add a new overlay on top of the previous overlay with opacity set to 1 and text within it.

Comment: Use the same css definition for a new overlay with exception of opacity and do not add any background.